# Leaflet: create individual Event-listeners inside For-loops

Tags: loops, events, leaflet, markers

I want want to put several markers on the map, these markers are consisting of *"parent" markers* and *"child" markers*. All parent markers should be visible on the map the same time, whereas the child-markers of a specific parent-marker should be toggled on/off if clicking onto the specific parent-marker

I created the following working example to demonstrate:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
 <title>Test 1</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
        html, body, #map {height: 100%;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
var thunder = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/neighbourhood/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {subdomains:'abc', attribution:'<a href="http://www.thunderforest.com">Thunderforest</a> | <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright/">OpenStreetMap</a>' });
var map = L.map('map',{layers: [thunder]}).setView([50.08, 10.08], 12);
var parent1 = L.marker([50.0, 10.0]).bindPopup('Marker 1');
var parent2 = L.marker([50.1, 10.1]).bindPopup('Marker 2');;
var layergroupParents = L.layerGroup([parent1, parent2]);

layergroupParents.addTo(map);

var child1a = L.marker([50.02, 10.02],{title: 'Child 1a'});
var child1b = L.marker([50.04, 10.04],{title: 'Child 1b'});
var layergroupChilds1 = L.layerGroup([child1a, child1b]);
var child2a = L.marker([50.12, 10.12],{title: 'Child 2a'});
var child2b = L.marker([50.14, 10.14],{title: 'Child 2b'});
var layergroupChilds2 = L.layerGroup([child2a, child2b]);

parent1.on('click', function(){
    if (map.hasLayer(layergroupChilds1)) {
     map.removeLayer(layergroupChilds1)
    } else {
        layergroupChilds1.addTo(map);
 }
});

parent2.on('click', function(){
    if (map.hasLayer(layergroupChilds2)) {
     map.removeLayer(layergroupChilds2)
    } else {
        layergroupChilds2.addTo(map);
 }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Since I want to display quite a lot markers, I want put the marker's properties into an Array ("markerArray") and process its markers by the help of For-Loops:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
 <title>Test 2</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
        html, body, #map {height: 100%;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
var thunder = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/neighbourhood/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {subdomains:'abc', attribution:'<a href="http://www.thunderforest.com">Thunderforest</a> | <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright/">OpenStreetMap</a>' });
var map = L.map('map',{layers: [thunder]}).setView([50.08, 10.08], 12);

var markerArray = [
  ["Marker 1", 50.0, 10.0, [["Child 1a", 50.02, 10.02], ["Child 1b", 50.04, 10.04]]],
  ["Marker 2", 50.1, 10.1, [["Child 1a", 50.12, 10.12], ["Child 1b", 50.14, 10.14]]], 
];

var numberParents = markerArray.length;
var layergroupParents = L.layerGroup();
for (cnt1=0; cnt1<numberParents; cnt1++) {
    var parentObject = L.marker([markerArray[cnt1][1], markerArray[cnt1][2]]);
    parentObject.bindPopup(markerArray[cnt1][0]);
    layergroupParents.addLayer (parentObject);

    var numberChilds = markerArray[cnt1][3].length;        
    var layergroupChilds = L.layerGroup();

    for (cnt2=0; cnt2<numberChilds; cnt2++) {
        var childObject = L.marker([markerArray[cnt1][3][cnt2][1], markerArray[cnt1][3][cnt2][2]], {title: markerArray[cnt1][3][cnt2][0]});
        layergroupChilds.addLayer (childObject);
    }

    parentObject.on('click', function(){
        if (map.hasLayer(layergroupChilds)) {
      map.removeLayer(layergroupChilds)
  } else {
            layergroupChilds.addTo(map);
  }
    }); 


}
layergroupParents.addTo(map);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you execute these script you will see, that there's some problem with assigning an individual 'click' event to each individual parent-marker. Right now just the child-markers of the **last parent-marker** are toggled on/off even if I click onto the first parent-marker.

Do you have an idea how I could solve these problem and Script 2 is working like in Script 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it to work, you have to attach the children to the parent (using a javascript property)

```
var layergroupChilds = L.layerGroup();
parentObject.layergroupChilds = layergroupChilds;
```

When parent receives a click, you can find the parent object in the event e, and hence its children.

```
parentObject.on('click', function(e){
    if (map.hasLayer(e.target.layergroupChilds)) {
        map.removeLayer(e.target.layergroupChilds)
    } else {
        e.target.layergroupChilds.addTo(map);
    }
});
```

Here is your [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/uzz1FpI3riB71YBpI6xX?p=preview) with corrections